# I need help to solve my matlab problem in plot surface

Tags: matlab

Please can anyone help me to solve my Matlab problem. I will share the question and it need to be solved in Matlab. Thanks in advance for your help.

[image: question]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: This is a really low quality question, all of the text you've written is filler, which boils down to "please answer this question for me", which is a given anyway for this Q&A site! Please read [ask], take the [tour], and only post *specific* questions, preferably with a [mcve] of what you've tried and why you're stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Using `meshgrid()` to Plot Surface

This method uses two vectors to set the axes. After creating the axes the grid over coordinates to plot over (domain) is created using the `meshgrid()`. The `meshgrid()` function will take two vectors that describe the axes. After creating this grid of coordinates the function `k` can be evaluated for all the points on the grid-pair.

[image: Surface Plot]

**For 6 ≤ n ≤ 12 (ten values) and 0.001 ≤ p ≤ 0.009 (five values):** 
Here you can see the top row of images showing the vectors used to create the axes. The second row of images shows the grid formation created using `meshgrid()`. You can see by taking one cell/value from `n` and one cell value from `p` a coordinate pair is formed → (n,p). For example, one coordinate point can be (n,p) → (6,0.0030).

[image: Case 1 Grid]

**For 6 ≤ n ≤ 12 (ten values) and 0.01 ≤ p ≤ 0.1 (ten values):**
[image: Case 2 Grid]

```
Number_Of_P_Ticks = 5;
P_Axis = linspace(0.001,0.009,Number_Of_P_Ticks);

Number_Of_N_Ticks = 10;
N_Axis = linspace(6,12,Number_Of_N_Ticks);

[p,n] = meshgrid(P_Axis,N_Axis);

k = -p.*n + sqrt((p.*n).^2 + (2.*p.*n));
subplot(1,2,1); surf(p,n,k,'FaceAlpha',0.9);
title("10 Values of p and 5 Values of n");
xlabel("p"); ylabel("n");

Number_Of_P_Ticks = 10;
P_Axis = linspace(0.01,0.1,Number_Of_P_Ticks);

[p,n] = meshgrid(P_Axis,N_Axis);

k = -p.*n + sqrt((p.*n).^2 + (2.*p.*n));
subplot(1,2,2); surf(p,n,k,'FaceAlpha',0.9);
title("10 Values of p and 10 Values of n");
xlabel("p"); ylabel("n");
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**

Comment: Answering questions which are as low quality as this one should be discouraged. It looks like you've put in a reasonable amount of effort here to make a complete answer - please spend that time helping people who have put a commensurate effort into their question! It reduces the chance of your answers being deleted along with low quality questions, and then doesn't encourage more low quality questions.

Comment: @Wolfie Thanks for the insight. I'll make sure to follow that and take that into account from now on.